# DataGridView call CellFormatting only once

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, background-color

I'm creating a dynamic DataGridView from a returned DB table. I need to change some cells to Red based on the value. I assigned a function to the **CellFormatting** event, but the function get called every time the user clicks on any cell/row (which slows down the form).

I would like to execute the function only on load.

I tried to set the style by looping the table, but the back color didn't change. I got it to work only when using the CellFormatting event.

**the code I have:**

```
this.dgv.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.Dgv_CellFormatting);
```

and in the function I change the color

```
    private void Dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                if ((int)e.Value >= 5)
                {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post any code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your code in "DataBindingComplete".

**Example**

```
private void dgv_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GridView_RowDataBound event .

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  //condition 
    If(e.Row.cells[3].Text.ToString() == "value2")
    {
    e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red // 
    }
}
```

Comment: this will run once per load or databind event. the DataControlRowType.Datarow ensures headers/footer are excluded from the loop

Comment: I can't find the RowDataBound event. this.dgv.* doesn't have this event.

Comment: Mike sorry my bad i was thinking webforms for winforms you could use DataGrid.LoadingRow , Occurs after a DataGridRow is instantiated, so that you can customize it before it is used. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.loadingrow(v=vs.110).aspx